# How can I run the example of hornetq, hierarchical project with Eclipse?

Tags: maven, hornetq

I'm stuck with running the clustered-queue.

The project is hierarchical project, depth is 3.

How can I run this example in Eclipse?

```
(root) --> https://github.com/verystrongjoe/hornetq
|  
└ pom.xml
      │
      └  exmaple folder
         │
         ├ pom.xml
         │
         └ jms folder
            │
            └ pom.xml
            │
            └ clustered-queue
               │
               └ pom.xml
```

Comment: Which version of Eclipse do you use? Basically you need to install the [Maven Integration (m2e)](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) plugin.  If you would like to checkout the project from github, the [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) should be suitable for you as well.

Comment: This question is based on a fork of some HornetQ repository. Rather than point to your own repository (which is unlikely to be helpful to future readers), can you try posting a question that is of more general interest, or actually using the official HornetQ repository?

Comment: ok, i accept your advice, Peter. I will consider when I ask to here next times.

Comment: @CharleeChitsuk thanks for reply. I already installed m2e and egit plugin and imported all projects. At first time, sing Egit, I downloaded all into my local disk. and  I used "Existing Maven Projects" and chose root Direcotry. so I could import all projects at one time. so I could procced to next things. is it correct?? i am not sure.. please let me clear.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the main official HornetQ project *master* branch https://github.com/hornetq/hornetq

1. **Follow the instructions at the end of the [README.mq](https://github.com/hornetq/hornetq/blob/master/README.md) for importing the project into Eclipse**. Seriously, there are detailed step-by-step instructions there. Although honestly most of those are for people that want to contribute code for the project.
2. Run any example you want by running them as *Maven* targets within Eclipse (many samples will need arguments and/or pre-steps, all of which are specified in the each example's pom.xml):

   - select the `pom.xml` of the example you want (in the maven sub-project of the example created during import);
   - `Run As` --> `Maven Build` (the first one), then set `Goal` to `verify`.

Notice, that you may need to install some sub-POM dependencies **if** running samples from a *SNAPSHOT* version (*as documented in the README.mq*).